# Adding sub classes to array lists then advanced for

Tags: java

```
private ArrayList<Doctor> doctors = new ArrayList<Doctor>();

doctors.add(new Doctor());
        doctors.add(new Doctor());
        doctors.add(new Doctor());

        doctors.add(new Surgeon());
        doctors.add(new Surgeon());
        doctors.add(new Surgeon());

for (Doctor doctor: doctors) {
            if (doctor.getAssignedPatient() != null) {
                if (doctor.aDayPasses()) {
                    System.out.println("A " + convertSpecialism(doctor.getSpecialism()) + " treated their patient.");
                    shortBreak();
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Works fine however when I try to do this:

```
        for (Surgeon doctor: doctors) {
            if (doctor.getAssignedPatient() != null) {
                if (doctor.aDayPasses()) {
                    System.out.println("A " + convertSpecialism(doctor.getSpecialism()) + " treated their patient.");
                    shortBreak();
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
```

There is a syntax error, how do I for loop through the surgeons I have added to the ArrayList of type doctor.

Assume that Surgeon extends doctor.

Comment: No it's the surgeon that extends doctor: public class Surgeon extends Doctor

Comment: Tell us the exact error and the row where you get it.

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Doctor to Surgeon, at for (Surgeon doctor: doctors) {

Comment: Yes, `user2177940`, you can't do what you're trying to do in the second snippet.  What's wrong with the code in the first snippet?

Comment: Ah, misread the problem statement, I thought the last code was the one that worked.

Comment: @DavidWallace Nothing wrong with the code in first snippet, I'm trying to find a way to read the surgeons I have added in the first snippet.

Comment: But you're doing that.  You're reading the surgeons.  What's the issue?

Comment: @DavidWallace Well when I run this code, it only reads the doctors. As the aDayPasses method is overridden in Surgeon and I need access to that.

Comment: But if `doctor` refers to a `Surgeon`, then `doctor.aDayPasses()` will run the version defined in the `Surgeon` class.  That's the whole point of polymorphism.

Comment: @DavidWallace But if I hover over the aDayPasses() call in Eclipse, it says boolean Doctor.aDayPasses(), when I want it to do boolean Surgeon.aDayPasses()

Comment: But when you RUN it, you'll get the right one.  What happens when you hover in Eclipse is entirely irrelevant to what your program actually does.

Comment: @DavidWallace But when I run it, the loop only reads doctors, doesn't read any of the surgeons.

Comment: YES IT DOES!!! It reads all of them.  Doctors and surgeons.  It doesn't skip anyone.

Comment: @DavidWallace But I've debugged it, and it only treats the patients of doctors, and not the patients of surgeons.

Comment: Then there's some other reason for that.  I guess either `doctor.getAssignedPatient()` is returning null, or `doctor.aDayPasses()` is returning false, in the cases that are being skipped.

Comment: Or most likely, the loop is ending because of the `break` statement inside the `else`.  Not sure why you want to have that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In two words: you can't. Because ArrayList contains Doctor, and you can't iterate that list as a list of Surgeons as Java doesn't support implicit downcasting. It is the same as assigning Doctor to Surgeon without explicitly downcasting.

So if you want to get Surgeon, you should explicitly convert it to Surgeon like this:

```
   for(Doctor d :doctors){
        if (d instanceof Surgeon){
            Surgeon s = (Surgeon) d;
            ...
        }
   }
```

But that's very bad practice and you shouldn't be doing it.

Comment: This won't make any difference to the result of any of the method calls that look like `doctor.something()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a for-each loop `(for (SubClass subClass : superClasses))` because the compiler cannot ensure that there are only objects of type `SubClass` (`Surgeon`) in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
for (Doctor doctor : doctors) {
    if (doctor instanceof Surgeon) {
        if (doctor.getAssignedPatient() != null) {
            if (doctor.aDayPasses()) {
                System.out.println("A "
                    + convertSpecialism(doctor.getSpecialism())
                    + " treated their patient.");
                shortBreak();
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there no better way to do this rather than using instanceof?

Comment: No, you don't need to do this at all.